# How do i create image from pixels stored as r, g, b each occupying different position in array?

Tags: java, image-processing, byte, bufferedimage

I am reading a .jpg image and accesing the pixels as:

```
if (type == BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR) {
   System.out.println("type.3byte.bgr");
   byte[] pixels = (byte[]) sourceImage.getData().getDataElements(0, 0, w, h, null);
}
```

// process this array called *pixels* and display the resulting image
// first i convert it to integer

```
int offseet=0;
   int[] data=new int[width*height*3];
   for ( i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
       data[i] = pixels[offset++] & 0xff;
     }
```

// and then process this array. *For now I am not processing it*. Now when i create a buffered 
//image from *data* array and display it the image displayed is not the same.
// the code i use is

```
 writeEdges(data);


private BufferedImage edgesImage;   
private void writeEdges(int arb[]) {
    if (edgesImage == null) {
    edgesImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }

    edgesImage.getWritableTile(0, 0).setDataElements(0, 0, width,height, arb);
 }
```

// for the penguins.jpg image(provided in sample pictures in windows 7)!

[image]

the output i get is

[image]

Comment: you have "offset" as "offseet" in the initializer

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  (The 2nd image is rather groovy, though - almost art.)  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how is your code running because it would not compile as jcomeau_ictx pointed out. The problem is that you use different image type for reading and writing.
Here is a code snippet that would generate the same image as the input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedImage sourceImage = null;
        try {
            sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new File("IScSH.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        int type = sourceImage.getType();
        int w = sourceImage.getWidth();
        int h = sourceImage.getHeight();
        byte[] pixels = null;
        if (type == BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR) {
            System.out.println("type.3byte.bgr");
            pixels = (byte[]) sourceImage.getData().getDataElements(0, 0, w, h, null);
        }
        try {
            BufferedImage edgesImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            edgesImage.getWritableTile(0, 0).setDataElements(0, 0, w, h, pixels);
            ImageIO.write(edgesImage, "jpg", new File("nvRhP.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ Rics: Thankyou Sir, but the problem is I am converting byte array to integer array, as i need to do some processing on pixels. So my new integer array displays the blue image above. In the try block code the type cant be TYPE_3BYTE_BGR for integer right?

Comment: Could you please tell me why there is a size difference between the original image and new constructed image?

Comment: There is a TYPE_INT_BGR type as well. Image size may depend on several things e.g. compression ratio. If the image looks what you want then I think you do not have to care about it.